# Filtering a data.frame that has same row and column names

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose I have a data.frame like this:

```
##              GNP.deflator   GNP Unemployed Armed.Forces Population  Year Employed
## GNP.deflator        1.000 0.992      0.621        0.465      0.979 0.991 0.971
## GNP                 0.992 1.000      0.604        0.446      0.991 0.995 0.984
## Unemployed          0.621 0.604      1.000       -0.177      0.687 0.668 0.502
## Armed.Forces        0.465 0.446     -0.177        1.000      0.364 0.417 0.457
## Population          0.979 0.991      0.687        0.364      1.000 0.994 0.960
## Year                0.991 0.995      0.668        0.417      0.994 1.000 0.971
## Employed            0.971 0.984      0.502        0.457      0.960 0.971 1.000
```

This is the result of running `cor(longley)` where `longley` is a built-in R dataset. How do I return the maximum of the results with the exception of 1. So here 0.995 would be the correct result. I've tried doing something like `max(cor(longley)[cor(longley)!=1, ])` but to no avail.

Comment: Just remove one `,`: `max(cor(longley)[cor(longley)!=1])`

Comment: Ohh! I was so close. Thanks! This is what I was looking for.

Comment: In case of duplicated columns (different column names but same values), `1` should be the expected result. Using `upper.tri` or `lower.tri` as in @GKi 's answer would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `upper.tri` or `lower.tri`:

```
x <- cor(longley)
max(x[upper.tri(x)])
#[1] 0.9952735
```

or exclude all `1` like you have tried:

```
max(x[x!=1])
#[1] 0.9952735
```

or exclude the diag:

```
max(x[upper.tri(x) | lower.tri(x)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the object `as.dist` so it keeps only the lower triangle, without the diagonal:

`max(as.dist(cor(longley)))`